# React Day Picker to array of dates excluding Disabled days

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, react-day-picker

I have an array of disabled dates. I tried the date rage click example from here http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/?range to get the updated **from** and **to** dates. However, I would to get an array of dates from the selected range instead of start and end dates and that excluding the disabled dates if any.

I think, I could use moment to calculate the difference between *from* and *to* dates to generate the array of dates for the range and that eliminates disabled dates with condition.

I would like to know is there any inbuilt helper function in **react-day-picker** that can do the same instead of doing this all by own. An Example would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the days in the range and populate an array with the included days:

```
let daysList = [];
if (range.from && range.to) {
  daysList = [range.from];

  while (daysList[daysList.length - 1] < range.to) {

    let day = daysList[daysList.length - 1];
    let dayToAdd = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate() + 1);

    if (!isDisabled(dayToAdd)) { // here check if the day is disabled
      daysList.push(dayToAdd);
    }
  }

  daysList.pop();
}
console.log("Selected days:", daysList)
```

See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/O7DOQ0R8r) using the range example.

You need to implement your own `isDisabled` function (it depends where you stored your disabled days), which could be like this:

```
disabledDays=[] // your array of disabled days
function isDisabled(day) {
  return disabledDays.find(disabledDay => 
     DateUtils.isSameDay(day, disabledDay)
  )
}
```